# How can I ensure that no other text is on the same line as my heading tag?

Tags: html, css

I have an h3 tag and I don't want to put any other tags in between it and the rest, but I can't seem to ensure that there is a line break before the rest of the text. How can I do this? Is it possible? I even tried `clear: both;`.

css:

```
.sidebar_info
{
    width:175px;
    padding:15px 10px 15px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background:url(img/info.png) no-repeat right top #ecf8fd;
    font-size:11px;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:17px;
}

.sidebar_info h3
{
    color:#49bae8;
    float:left;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:400;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    clear: both;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="sidebar_info"><h3>RAWR!</h3>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</div>
```

Comment: Remove the `float: left`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `float: left;` for your `h3` element which is a block level element in nature, so when you float left, the rest of the space gets empty, and thus leads the text besides it to move up in the rest of the available space, so why float it to the left when you need a break after that?

If you need the text to be aligned left, right or centered simply use `text-align` property with `left, right, or center` as the values

And if you still need a break(Which you don't even need in this case if you simply remove the `float`) than self clear your `h3` element like this

```
.sidebar_info h3:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: That `.sidebar_info h3:after` doesn't cause a break.

Comment: @Pachonk Why you are using `float`, just don't use it?

Comment: I took float off, still won't jump the rest of the text to the next line.

Comment: I used inspect element, it was grabbing my standard `h3{}` css style... Thanks!